# Tags on review page

Tags: support, tags, review-queues, vote-to-close, filtering

Just noticed that Stack Overflow now offers instant tag filtering for the *Close Votes* review queue:

[image]

I suppose these tags contain the majority of close-voted questions. Is this true?

Comment: I have the exact same list of tags, so I think you're right.

Comment: A personalized list of tags would be a good idea here. I have no interest in the php/html/js/jquery ghetto...

Comment: Is this enabled on all sites?

Comment: @Braiam: haven't seen it elsewhere yet.

Comment: Maybe this got implemented http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209778/213575

Comment: @Braiam you were right. Confirmation of actual implementation was just put up here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231856/216322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those tags represent the questions with the most close votes in the queue.

As pointed out by [chue x](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1822514/chue-x) the feature got implemented in May, 2014 and was announced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231856) by [m0sa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/156631/m0sa).

Keep in mind that the tags you see there are not personalized. Your ignored or favorite tags are not taken into account. If you're interested in the ranking of all the tags (give or take 7 days) in the queue,  use this rough SEDE [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508983):

```sql
select t.tagname, count(*)
from pendingflags pf
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = pf.id
inner join tags t on pt.tagid = t.id
where flagtypeid = 14 -- close
group by t.tagname
order by count(*) desc
```